# Google Maps API -- adding simple buttons to turn left, turn right, etc

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, button, onclick

I'm using the Google Maps API, working in JavaScript/HTML. I'm trying to add simple buttons. If the user presses these buttons, it will turn left, turn right, etc on the map. However, my function changeHeading is being called, but not executing after it's called. What is the problem?

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Street View Add Third Panel</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #map {
                float: left;
                height: 50%;
                width: 50%;
            }
            #pano {
                width: 100%;
                height: 50%;
            }
            #floating-panel {
                float: right;
                width: 50%;
                height: 50%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <div id="floating-panel">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Position</b></td><td id="position-cell">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>POV Heading</b></td><td id="heading-cell">270</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>POV Pitch</b></td><td id="pitch-cell">0.0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Pano ID</b></td><td id="pano-cell">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <input type="button" value="Turn Left" onclick="changeHeading(-5);">
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <input type="button" value="Turn Right" onclick="changeHeading(-5);">
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <input type="button" value="Go Forward" onclick="changeHeading(-5);">
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <input type="button" value="Go Backward" onclick="changeHeading(-5);">
            </tr>
            <table id="links_table"></table>
        </table></div>



        <div id="pano"></div>
    <script>

    function initialize() {
        var fenway = {lat: 42.345573, lng: -71.098326};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: fenway,
            zoom: 14
        });
        var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
            document.getElementById('pano'), {
                position: fenway,
                pov: {
                    heading: 34,
                    pitch: 10
                }
            });
        map.setStreetView(panorama);

        panorama.addListener('pano_changed', function() {
            var panoCell = document.getElementById('pano-cell');
            panoCell.innerHTML = panorama.getPano();
        });
        panorama.addListener('links_changed', function() {
            var linksTable = document.getElementById('links_table');
            while (linksTable.hasChildNodes()) {
                linksTable.removeChild(linksTable.lastChild);
            }
            var links = panorama.getLinks();
            for (var i in links) {
                var row = document.createElement('tr');
                linksTable.appendChild(row);
                var labelCell = document.createElement('td');
                labelCell.innerHTML = '<b>Link: ' + i + '</b>';
                var valueCell = document.createElement('td');
                valueCell.innerHTML = links[i].description;
                linksTable.appendChild(labelCell);
                linksTable.appendChild(valueCell);
            }
        });
        panorama.addListener('position_changed', function() {
            var positionCell = document.getElementById('position-cell');
            positionCell.firstChild.nodeValue = panorama.getPosition() + '';
        });
        panorama.addListener('pov_changed', function() {
            var headingCell = document.getElementById('heading-cell');
            var pitchCell = document.getElementById('pitch-cell');
            headingCell.firstChild.nodeValue = panorama.getPov().heading + '';
            pitchCell.firstChild.nodeValue = panorama.getPov().pitch + '';
        });


    }

    function changeHeading( delta ) {
        heading = panorama.getPov().heading;
        panorama.setPov({ heading: heading + delta });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Panorama is a local variable and not available to changeHeading() function.
Do two things:

1. Define *var panorama = null;* outside the functions as a global variable.
2. Remove **var** from "*var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(...*" so it does not create a new local variable and use the global one instead.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. panorama is a local variable, so is not accessible in the button onclick function (which runs in the global scope).  You can fix that by using the `google.maps.event.addDomListener` function in the scope that it is defined in.
2. When you set the POV you need to set it with a POV object (otherwise you will get javascript errors `InvalidValueError: setPov: in property pitch: not a number`)

(inside `initMap`):

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("left"),'click', function() {changeHeading(-5)});
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("right"),'click', function() {changeHeading(5)});

function changeHeading(delta) {
  var heading = panorama.getPov().heading;
  var POV = panorama.getPov();
  POV.heading = heading + delta;
  panorama.setPov(POV);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/q6rszsr9/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var fenway = {
    lat: 42.345573,
    lng: -71.098326
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: fenway,
    zoom: 14
  });
  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById('pano'), {
      position: fenway,
      pov: {
        heading: 34,
        pitch: 10
      }
    });
  map.setStreetView(panorama);

  panorama.addListener('pano_changed', function() {
    var panoCell = document.getElementById('pano-cell');
    panoCell.innerHTML = panorama.getPano();
  });
  panorama.addListener('links_changed', function() {
    var linksTable = document.getElementById('links_table');
    while (linksTable.hasChildNodes()) {
      linksTable.removeChild(linksTable.lastChild);
    }
    var links = panorama.getLinks();
    for (var i in links) {
      var row = document.createElement('tr');
      linksTable.appendChild(row);
      var labelCell = document.createElement('td');
      labelCell.innerHTML = '<b>Link: ' + i + '</b>';
      var valueCell = document.createElement('td');
      valueCell.innerHTML = links[i].description;
      linksTable.appendChild(labelCell);
      linksTable.appendChild(valueCell);
    }
  });
  panorama.addListener('position_changed', function() {
    var positionCell = document.getElementById('position-cell');
    positionCell.firstChild.nodeValue = panorama.getPosition() + '';
  });
  panorama.addListener('pov_changed', function() {
    var headingCell = document.getElementById('heading-cell');
    var pitchCell = document.getElementById('pitch-cell');
    headingCell.firstChild.nodeValue = panorama.getPov().heading + '';
    pitchCell.firstChild.nodeValue = panorama.getPov().pitch + '';
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("left"), 'click', function() {
    changeHeading(-5)
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("right"), 'click', function() {
    changeHeading(5)
  });

  function changeHeading(delta) {
    var heading = panorama.getPov().heading;
    var POV = panorama.getPov();
    POV.heading = heading + delta;
    panorama.setPov(POV);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  float: left;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

#pano {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

#floating-panel {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="floating-panel">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Position</b></td>
      <td id="position-cell">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>POV Heading</b></td>
      <td id="heading-cell">270</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>POV Pitch</b></td>
      <td id="pitch-cell">0.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Pano ID</b></td>
      <td id="pano-cell">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <input type="button" id="left" value="Turn Left" onclick="changeHeading(-5);">
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <input type="button" id="right" value="Turn Right" onclick="changeHeading(5);">
    </tr>
    <table id="links_table"></table>
  </table>
</div>



<div id="pano"></div>
```